# how to convert pdf file data read through file_get_contents to readable utf-8 character set format with PHP

Tags: php, pdf, character-encoding, file-get-contents, iconv

I am trying to read and process contents from a **.pdf** file.The target with this process is not to use any extraneous libraries that are not attached with the raw PHP bootstrap installation.I have tried to use **file_get_contents** to store the read content into a string variable.The problem is on **echo**-ing this content,it is all gibberish.

This,I can say,was expected since the character encoding is different from browser supported formats.I tried to use PHP's **iconv** function to convert the encoding from ASCII to utf-8,CP1252 to utf-8 and vice versa but none spawned readable output.

So the question is,what is the character encoding associated with **.pdf** files and how does one convert read content from such files to browser supported character encoding.Thanks.

Comment: First, you do realize that pdf files are binary files with their own format (like docx files) and that a simply 're-encoding' will never fix that issue, you need to be able to convert and read the entire pdf (so, look in to that).

Comment: Okay,I had the impression that file_get_contents would have dealt with that situation.Thanks for the insightful input,let me try to investigate.

Comment: Okay so it seems that the binary information,checked with finfo_file,is in ASCII strings,so basically file_get_contents actually should be able to get the entire .pdf file as a string.This is explained in my question,my problem is just making this string legible.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format#Technical_foundations  More specifically: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format#Text

Comment: It is possible to create a PDF file whose bytes are from the range of ASCII codes only (even though this generally is not done these days anymore). This doesn't mean, though, immediate readability. Simply open a PDF in a text editor to get a first impression.

Comment: I know,its what I am experiencing hence the question,I need to convert those ASCII code sets to readable utf-8 format strings.

Comment: @pmrutu So in essence you need some PDF parsing library (with methods extracting the text from the content if possible). If you really don't want to use a third-party library, you need to implement the methods yourself. As a primer you might start by studying the specification [ISO 32000-1:2008](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) with a focus on the chapters 7, 8, and 9.